# Blocked by CORS policy 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' using controller response.redirect

Tags: node.js, express, cors

I have an issue with response redirect in specific controller which i cant understand why.
my app works fine with the cors and other controllers. i'm using node js and express.

Take a look in bar controller

```
export const bar = async (request: Request, response: Response) => {
  try {
    const loginToken = generateToken()
    response.redirect(`${baseUrlFE}/login/${loginToken}`);
  } catch (error: any) {
    res.status(403).send({ message: error.message, type: "Error" });
  }
};
```

In FE i got

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:3000/login/someToken' (redirected from 'http://localhost:8000/bar/route') from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'.
```

This is my cors middleware

```
function cors(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) {
  const allowedOrigins = ["http://localhost:3000"] 

  const origin = req.headers.origin as string;
  if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
  }

  // tests
  // console.log("Received origin:", origin);
  // console.log("Allowed origins:", allowedOrigins);

  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
  res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");


  next();
}
```

The cors works fine for other controllers as i said but dont understand what is the issue here. Also if i paste the full redirect link to new tab it will work correct. the issue is the cors block me somehow and i don't understand

Answer (score 0):

it would help if you verified first whether your origin is coming or not into your code:-

```
const origin = req.headers.origin as string;
  if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);
  }
```

**I'm not sure maybe the issue is in the following condition**:-

```
const origin = req.headers.origin as string;
      if (allowedOrigins.includes(origin)) {
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin);//maybe origin was not set into header
```

**Also you want to add this line into your method in FE**

```
credentials: 'include'
```

an example if your FE is angular:-

```
corsIssue() {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8000/bar/route';
    return this.http.get(url, { withCredentials: true });
  }
```

**FYI** you can use a third-party package also for cors:-

[https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors]